# Selector.shouldRebuild is not used and always rebuild widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

### Versions

```
provider 6.0.5 (current latest)
Flutter 3.13.7
Dart 3.1.3
```

### Code example

https://dartpad.dev/?id=50e340da1ea3c75f0aa66a32394db32d

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ChangeNotifierProvider<MyState>(
          create: (context) => MyState(),
          child: const Body(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyState with ChangeNotifier {
  List<int> values = [0, 0, 0];
  void increment(int key) {
    values[key]++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  const Body({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var values = context.watch<MyState>().values;
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
              Selector<MyState, int>(
                selector: (_, state) {
                  print("Selector  index: $i, selector: ${state.values[i]}");
                  return state.values[i];
                },
                shouldRebuild: (previous, next) {
                  print(
                      "Should    index: $i, prev: $previous, next: $next ${previous != next ? ", NEED REBUILD" : ""}");
                  return previous != next;
                },
                builder: (_, __, ___) {
                  print("Build     index: $i");
                  return Expanded(
                      child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                    "${values[i]}",
                    textScaleFactor: 3,
                  )));
                },
              )
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
              Expanded(
                child: Center(
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("-" * 20);
                      print("Increment index: $i");
                      context.read<MyState>().increment(i);
                    },
                    child: Text("Increment $i"),
                  ),
                ),
              )
          ],
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text(
            "Summ: ${values.reduce((value, element) => value + element)}",
            textScaleFactor: 2,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

### Output

```
Selector  index: 0, selector: 0
Build     index: 0
Selector  index: 1, selector: 0
Build     index: 1
Selector  index: 2, selector: 0
Build     index: 2
--------------------
Increment index: 1
Selector  index: 0, selector: 0
Build     index: 0
Selector  index: 1, selector: 1
Build     index: 1
Selector  index: 2, selector: 0
Build     index: 2
```

### Problem

`build` is always called.
`shouldRebuild` is never called.

### Question

What am I doing wrong?

### P.S.

If change
final shouldInvalidateCache = oldWidget != widget ||
to
final shouldInvalidateCache = oldWidget == null ||
in [provider/lib/src/selector.dart](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/blob/7200ac75192ad74f7bfbe2cae93f56d17dd9e648/packages/provider/lib/src/selector.dart#L77)
then all work good:

```
Increment index: 1
Selector  index: 0, selector: 0
Should    index: 0, prev: 0, next: 0 
Selector  index: 1, selector: 1
Should    index: 1, prev: 0, next: 1 , NEED REBUILD
Build     index: 1
Selector  index: 2, selector: 0
Should    index: 2, prev: 0, next: 0
```

Comment: Try replacing watch with read in first line of build method.

Comment: @Rahul, thanks. It works, but I need a `watch` in the `build`. Please look at the new version of the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `.watch` methods rebuilds the tree, which rebuilds `Selector` each time, making it never get to `shouldRebuild`.

**Solution:**
Change the watch method to read, cause it's only needed once to build the related widgets.

```dart
// change
var values = context.watch<MyState>().values;
// to
var values = context.read<MyState>().values;
```

Instead of using `.watch` results to update the sum, use a consumer.

```dart
// change
Text(
  "Summ: ${values.reduce((value, element) => value + element)}",
  textScaleFactor: 2,
),
//to
Consumer<MyState>(
  builder: (context, state, child) {
    return Text(
      "Summ: ${state.values.reduce((value, element) => value + element)}",
      textScaleFactor: 2,
    );
  },
)
```

**Bonus**
You may access the MyState value from builder in selector.

```dart
// this
builder: (_, __, ___) {
  return Expanded(
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        "${values[i]}",
        textScaleFactor: 3,
      ),
    ),
  );
},
// to
builder: (_, value, ___) {
  return Expanded(
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        "$value",
        textScaleFactor: 3,
      ),
    ),
  );
},
```